# jQuery scrolltop not working on mobile

Tags: jquery

This is my html where search results will be shown upon search button click

```
 <div class="the-return" id="view2">

   <div class="the-inner-return">


   </div>

   <div class="the-inner-return2">


   </div>

   <div class="the-inner-return3">


   </div>

    <div id="the-return-fail" class="text-center">
      <h1>Unsuccessful Search!</h1>
      <h2 id="refine">Refine search!</h2>

   </div>
   </div>
```

and my script

```
<script>
$("#search").on("click",function(){
    // Handler for .ready() called.
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('#view2').offset().top
    }, 'slow');
});
</script>
```

Now the idea is, to scrolltop to div id= view2 when search button clicked.The view2 div is placed right above the search results which will occupy these divs `the-inner-return,the-inner-return2 and the-inner-return3`.

Now it works for dekstop.Even when I resize the browser to mobile screen it works also. But on actual mobile device its not? I really wonder why? I have no clue what went wrong here.

Or is there any alternative way to achieve this please?

Answer (score 0):

**Maybe this will help you...**

```
<script>
$("#search").on("click",function(){
// Handler for .ready() called.
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop:$('#view2').parent().scrollTop() + $('#view2').offset().top - $('#view2').parent().offset().top
}, 'slow');
});
</script>
```

Comment: thank you..could you please explain the code as well if you don't mind? Why do we have .parent(),offset()?